# Checking whether a Session exists, if not creating a new session in VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session

I'm new to this so I'm having a difficult time figuring this thing.

I have a ASP.Net application which has two controls, **'lblSessionState'** which has a value - "There is no session"
**'btnSessionState'** which has a value - "Start Session"

What i want to know is how to check whether a Session exists. For example, how do I check whether there is a Session called **"MySession"** and if that exists how to assign its value to **'lblSessionState'** as text value.

If **"MySession"** does not exist how do I create it and assign a value.

Also I want to know when a button is clicked how to detect the post back and clear the session.

Thank you so much in advance.....

Answer (score 0):

HYG

```
if(Session["MySession"]==null)
    Session["MySession"] = "Your value";

lblSessionState.Text = Session["MySession"].ToString();
```

check the following link for more details http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_sessions.asp

Comment: Yeah thanks for that. But can you help me with this.  When i click the button it should post back to itself, detect the postback and clear the session using Session.Abandon

Comment: HYG, simply open the page and drag button to it then in the designer mode double click on the button which will generate the necessary code to link between the button and postback